# MySQL: Select only rows where X is not included in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a little trouble getting this to work exactly how I want it to work. I have a table called `users` and then I have a table called `friendships`.

Every time someone sends a friend request and it gets accepted, the friendship is added to a log that contains `requester`,`accepter`.

Now I have a page where all users are located and you can friend them. How would I go about not showing people on this page that are already friended by me (through looking at the `friendships` table/logs).

Comment: Just select some stuff from over here and left join it to some stuff over there.

Comment: Please post your tables structure as well

Comment: having a *direction* in your friendship makes it awkward to query - your data model suggests it matters who initiated the friendship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it by using NOT IN together with an array containing all the friendship IDs.